# open graph meta tags for drupal works sometimes

Tags: drupal, facebook-opengraph

So I am using the open graph meta tag module for drupal 6.0. Sometimes, when I paste an article url (on my site) into my facebook, the open graph images, description, etc shows up, but other times it does not. What can I do to make these show up all the time?

Can side loading time be a factor? If the site loads slow, can that affect the open graph images showing up or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on when the article was *scraped*.

> Facebook scrapes your page every 24 hours to ensure the properties are up to date. The page is also scraped when an admin for the Open Graph page clicks the Like button and when the URL is entered into the Facebook URL Linter. Facebook observes cache headers on your URLs - it will look at "Expires" and "Cache-Control" in order of preference. However, even if you specify a longer time, Facebook will scrape your page every 24 hours.

<sub>Source: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/</sub>